# get PNG representation of NSImage in swift

Tags: swift

Hey I'm having some trouble with getting the PNG representation of an NSImage object.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var imgData: NSData! = coverImgView.image!.TIFFRepresentation!
var bitmap: NSBitmapImageRep! = NSBitmapImageRep(data: imgData!)
var pngCoverImage = bitmap!.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSPNGFileType, properties: nil)
```

coverImgView is an NSImageView object

However, I cannot even get it compiled somehow.

It says: Type '[NSObject: AnyObject]' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible' (the third line of the code I post above, argument "properties: nil")

I'm trying to do something similar to the function "PNGRepresentationOfImage" here https://gist.github.com/mtabini/1178403

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation says:

```
func representationUsingType(_ storageType: NSBitmapImageFileType,
              properties properties: [NSObject : AnyObject]) -> NSData?
```

So it expects a dictionary, not a nil value. Supply an empty dict like this:

```
var pngCoverImage = bitmap!.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSPNGFileType, properties: [:])
```

Only if an Optional is specified (that is it where `[NSObject : AnyObject]?)` you could pass a nil value.